# Update record based on oid (string)

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

i saw some posts saying to use Long id with another key(as index and unique), if i understood correctly, this will update based on another field(not id based) or more, my class:

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "tbl_company") 
public class Company { 

@Id(autoincrement = true) 
private Long company_id; 

@Index(unique = true) 
@SerializedName(value = "oid") 
public String oid;
```

give me this exception -> UNIQUE constraint failed: tbl_company.OID

of course i understand why this happens, but the doubt is WHY people say this should work to update the row with index/unique based in this configurations.

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "tbl_company",indexes = { 

@Index(value = "oid", unique = true)} ) 
public class Company {
@Id(autoincrement = true) 
private Long company_id; 

@SerializedName(value = "oid") 
public String oid;
```

error: `Cannot update entity without key - was it inserted before?` 
I understand it too, i should set the id, but the information come from server without the sqlite ID, only the MongoDB oid:

```
.update 
.update 
.updateInTx 
.insertOrReplace 
.insertOrReplaceInTx
```

i know i can query for oid to check if its exist, but i was trying to just use `updateInTx` for many objects at once. Using the query approach i should iterate and check for each one, get id, set id on new and than update, maybe this can impact the performance (sometimes server can return at least 500 items to iterate)

is there a really a way to update the row using another field rather than ID or im doing wrong?  (i dont care about the id, just the oid is important and must be unique and can be updated)